# Will XmlSuite.SetFileName(XXX) create a physical file?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver, testng

Can we convert virtually created XML file into physically? For example, I'm generating `testng.xml` file programmatically and execute my test scripts along with that.

My expectation is, I need to create an XML file which is virtually created as I said above... I have used the below code but it’s not producing expected results.

```
    TestNG myTestNG = new TestNG();

     XmlSuite mySuite = new XmlSuite();
     mySuite.setName("MySuite");
     mySuite.setParallel(XmlSuite.ParallelMode.METHODS);

     XmlTest myTest = new XmlTest(mySuite);
     myTest.setName("MyTest");

    myTest.setParameters(testngParams);

     List<XmlClass> myClasses = new ArrayList<XmlClass> ();
     myClasses.add(new XmlClass("ThreadSample"));

     myTest.setXmlClasses(myClasses);

     List<XmlTest> myTests = new ArrayList<XmlTest>();
     myTests.add(myTest);

    //add the list of tests to your Suite.
     mySuite.setTests(myTests);

    //Add the suite to the list of suites.
     List<XmlSuite> mySuites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
     mySuites.add(mySuite);

     XmlSuite suite = getXmlSuite();
     mySuites.add(suite);

     myTestNG.setXmlSuites(mySuites);

     **suite.setFileName("user.dir" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "myVirtual.xml");
     System.out.println("File generated successfully.");**

     myTestNG.setSuiteThreadPoolSize(3);
     myTestNG.setThreadCount(3);

     myTestNG.run();
```

Can anyone help me to complete this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a physical testNG.xml file, you have to write the suites object at a given location.

```
FileWriter writer;
try {
writer = new FileWriter(new File("myVirtual.xml"));
writer.write(mySuites.toXml());
writer.flush();
writer.close();
System.out.println(new File("myVirtual.xml").getAbsolutePath());
} catch (IOException e) {

e.printStackTrace();
}
```